# AccessControl: Unable to set target charset (adequate stub not found?) nsis

Tags: nsis

while adding AccessControl NSIS fails with below error
**Error: Can't change target architecture after data already got compressed or header already changed!
Error: Unable to set target charset (adequate stub not found?)**

This is what i added in nsis, installed the plugin (pasted the dll in right folders), restarted the NSIS v3 app.

AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$INSTDIR" "(S-1-5-32-545)" "FullAccess"
Pop $0

```
 ;RequestExecutionLevel user

!include "MUI2.nsh"
!define MUI_INSERT_NSISCONF
BrandingText "Brand"
;!addplugindir "AccessControl\Unicode\Plugins"
  

!macro MUI_NSISCONF

    !define MUI_BGCOLOR "SYSCLR:Window" 
    !define MUI_ICON "H:\Personal\learning\AI\App\app.ico"
    !define MUI_UNICON "H:\Personal\learning\AI\App\app.ico"

    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
    
    
!macroend


Section "Install" SecDummy

  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

  ;Store installation folder
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App" "DisplayName" "App"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App" "UninstallString" "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App" "InstallLocation" "$INSTDIR"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App" "Publisher" "publisher"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App" "DisplayVersion" "2.1.4.0"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App" "DisplayIcon" "$INSTDIR\app.ico"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App" "NoModify" 1
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App" "NoRepair" 1
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App" "QuietUninstallString" "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"
    createShortCut "$STARTMENU\Programs\App.lnk" "$INSTDIR\App.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\app.ico"
    
    
    ;AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$INSTDIR\App.exe" "(BU)" "FullAccess"
    ;Pop $0
    AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$INSTDIR" "(S-1-5-32-545)" "FullAccess"
    Pop $0
    ;AccessControl::GrantOnRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App" "(BU)" "FullAccess"
    ;Pop $0
    ;AccessControl::GrantOnRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App" "(S-1-5-32-545)" "FullAccess"
    ;Pop $0
  ;Create uninstaller
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

SectionEnd

Section "Uninstall"

  Delete "$INSTDIR\*"

  RMDir "$INSTDIR"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\App"
  delete "$STARTMENU\Programs\App.lnk"

SectionEnd


Function .onInstSuccess
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR
    Exec '"App.exe"'
FunctionEnd
```

can someone please help to resolve the issue

Comment: You should not be granting full access to these things.

Comment: i tried all possible options that would work but nothing worked, all operations results in same error

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what the exact problem is because you have not posted enough code but I can guess:

- You are trying to target something you don't have the required stub files for, for example if your .nsi has `Target amd64-unicode`.
- You are trying to change the target too late in your script. `Unicode` and/or `Target` should be as early as possible in your .nsi, before !includes and functions/sections.

Try this to make sure a simple script works:

```
!verbose 4
Unicode True
!echo "NSIS ${NSIS_VERSION} (${NSIS_PACKEDVERSION}, CS=${NSIS_CHAR_SIZE}, ${NSIS_CPU})"
!echo "Choosing zlib-x86-unicode (${NSISDIR})"
SetCompressor /Final zlib
!if /FileExists "${NSISDIR}\Stubs\zlib-x86-unicode"
    !echo "Stub exists, everything should be OK"
!else
    !warning "Stub not there? Reinstall NSIS?"
!endif
!ifdef NSIS_WIN32_MAKENSIS
    !echo "Compiling on Windows"
!endif
!ifdef NSIS_UNICODE_MAKENSIS
    !echo "Using Unicode compiler"
!endif

Section
SectionEnd
```

It should output something like this:

```
MakeNSIS v3.08 - Copyright 1999-2021 Contributors
See the file COPYING for license details.
Credits can be found in the Users Manual.

Processing config: C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\nsisconf.nsh
Processing script file: "C:\Test.nsi" (ACP)
Unicode: true
Processing default plugins: "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Plugins\x86-unicode\*.dll"

NSIS v3.08 (0x03008000, CS=2, x86) (C:\Test.nsi:3)
Choosing zlib-x86-unicode (C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS) (C:\Test.nsi:4)
SetCompressor: /FINAL zlib
Stub exists, everything should be OK (C:\Test.nsi:7)
Compiling on Windows (C:\Test.nsi:12)
Using Unicode compiler (C:\Test.nsi:13)
Section: ""
SectionEnd

Processed 1 file, writing output (x86-unicode):
Processing pages... Done!
Removing unused resources... Done!
Generating language tables... Done!

Output: "C:\Test.exe"
Install: 1 page (64 bytes), 1 section (1 required) (4144 bytes), 2 instructions (56 bytes), 23 strings (546 bytes), 1 language table (194 bytes).

Using zlib compression.

EXE header size:               38400 / 39936 bytes
Install code:                    474 / 5396 bytes
Install data:                      0 / 0 bytes
CRC (0x6FE2CBE1):                  4 / 4 bytes

Total size:                    38878 / 45336 bytes (85.7%)
```

Comment: HI @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501/anders I've updated the question with full .nsi code, can you please verify once

Comment: adding Unicode true as line 1 didn't resolved the issue

Comment: Try the script I just added